# [Morse simulation]Module not found: No module named 'morse.middleware.ros_request_manager'

Tags: ros, morse, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI there,

I'm trying to use the Morse simulation but find some problems while run the tutorial"examples/tutorials/tutorial-1-ros.py".
The error is as follow:

```
[helpers.loading] Module not found: No module named 'morse.middleware.ros_request_manager'
[helpers.loading] Could not load the class RosRequestManager in morse.middleware.ros_request_manager
[helpers.loading] Could not create an instance of morse.middleware.ros_request_manager.RosRequestManager
[core.services] Request Manager morse.middleware.ros_request_manager.RosRequestManager not found. Check for typos in the configuration file!
```

I've already installed the python3.4 and other elements which tutorials indicates.
[link text](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/latest/user/installation/mw/ros.html)

And also refered the answer:
[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/85211/importerror-no-module-named-rospkg-on-hydro-solved/)
But still cannot solve the problem.

Any ideas of this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250853/%5Bmorse-simulation%5Dmodule-not-found:-no-module-named-%27morse.middleware.ros_request_manager%27/) by [jiangqueque](https://answers.ros.org/users/28905/jiangqueque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-28**:
This would really seem to be a problem with Morse and one of its plugins, would you agree? I would suggest you ask this question on a Morse support forum, as you stand a much better chance of getting (good) answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
Can you tell us:

- What version of Ubuntu & ROS are you using?
- How you have installed MORSE?

...since quite a while, MORSE supports ROS 'out of the box', and does not require any particular ROS configuration steps.

---

Originally posted by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) with karma: 240 on 2016-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jiangqueque](https://answers.ros.org/users/28905/jiangqueque/) on 2017-01-05**:
Ubuntu 14.04
Ros 1.11.19
I've already installed MORSE, and launched a simple simulation by using command:

```
$ morse create mysim
$ morse run mysim
```

I want to develop a vehicle dynamic model by MORSE on ROS, so I need to use ROS modules.
Does MORSE support my Ubuntu & ROS version?